# Cannot run mobile app when I use SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a problem with my code, exactly database part of my code:
    I used a class named Database extends "SQLiteOpenHelper" and I create in it :

```
public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " +
Data_table.Table_info.STUDENTS_TABLE + "(" + Data_table.Table_info.COL1
+ " TEXT," + Data_table.Table_info.COL2 + " TEXT,"
Data_table.Table_info.COL3 + " TEXT," + Data_table.Table_info.COL4 + 
" TEXT );"; 

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase mydata) {

    mydata.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
    Log.d("Database" , "The first table created");
}
```

And I create that method : put_informations

[image]

In the main activity called the method witch is cleared in this photo:

[image]

Comment: What error are u getting ? Show the logcat please.

Comment: You have not told us what the problem is.

Comment: This is my Database class, and the problem's whene i click on the button of saving database, it show to me the note: "the app ifortuntly has stopped"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple code for creating DB and inserting the data to it if that was your question, if not please clarify it a little more.

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "yourDBname.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "yourtablename";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "yourCol2";

public DBHelper_input(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table "+ TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, yourCol2 INTEGER,COLUMN_TIME_STAMP TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+ TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}

public boolean insertData(String yourCol2){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,yourCol2);
    long reuslt = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    if (reuslt == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

}